# Connection issue with nginx and php-fpm on ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Tags: nginx, web-server, php-fpm, cloudflare

I am not able to contact my website which has been set up on a freshly installed ubuntu server 22.04 LTS. Unfortunately, my connection attempts time out with error 522 and I have no idea where to start looking for the problem. Therefore, I am going to explain what I did so far and what I've already checked. I woulkd greatly appreciate any input on possible steps to take next!

Thank you for your help in advance. It is highly appreciated.

1. I started on a fresh ubuntu 22.04 LTS and started with the installation of php8.1-fpm and a few complementary packages from ppa:ondrej/php

   `apt install php8.1-fpm php8.1-json php8.1-zip php8.1-gd  php8.1-mbstring php8.1-curl php8.1-xml php-pear libtool`
2. Next step installation of nginx:

   ```
   curl https://nginx.org/keys/nginx_signing.key | gpg --dearmor \
   | tee /usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg >/dev/null“
   OS=$(lsb_release -is | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
   RELEASE=$(lsb_release -cs)
   echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/nginx-archive-keyring.gpg] \
   http://nginx.org/packages/${OS} ${RELEASE} nginx" \
   | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx.list
   apt update && apt -y upgrade && apt install -y nginx
   ```
3. Installation of certbot with support for cloudflare & setup of SSL certificates

   ```
   snap install core; sudo snap refresh core
   snap install --classic certbot
   ln -s /snap/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot
   snap set certbot trust-plugin-with-root=ok
   snap install certbot-dns-cloudflare
   mkdir /root/.secrets/ && touch /root/.secrets/cf.ini
   echo "dns_cloudflare_api_token=$cftoken" >> /root/.secrets/cf.ini
   chmod 0700 /root/.secrets/
   chmod 0600 /root/.secrets/cf.ini
   mkdir -p /etc/letsencrypt
   openssl dhparam -out /etc/letsencrypt/dhparam.pem 4096
   certbot certonly --agree-tos \
     --no-eff-email \
     --rsa-key-size 4096 \
     --dns-cloudflare \
     --dns-cloudflare-credentials /root/.secrets/cf.ini \
     --dns-cloudflare-propagation-seconds 60 \
     --preferred-challenges dns-01 \
     -m $webmail \
     -d $hostname \
     -d *.$hostname
   ```
4. Setup of website Dir ($sitedir), transfer of files and permission fix

   ```
   mkdir -p /var/www/mydomain.com/public
   chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www
   find /var/www -type f -exec chmod 0640 {} \;
   find /var/www -type d -exec chmod 2750 {} \;
   ```
5. Setup of nginx based on https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx

   ```
   nginx -s stop
   cd /etc
   mv nginx nginx-previous
   git clone https://github.com/h5bp/server-configs-nginx.git nginx
   cd /etc/nginx/conf.d
   cp templates/example.com.conf .mydomain.com.conf
   sed -i 's/example.com/mydomain.com/g' .mydomain.com.conf
   mv .mydomain.com.conf mydomain.com.conf
   nginx -s reload
   ```

   After some more tweaks I ended up with the following configuration of nginx

   ```
   user www-data;
   worker_processes auto;
   worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;
   events {

     worker_connections 8000;

   }

   # Log errors and warnings to this file
   # This is only used when you don't override it on a `server` level
   error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

   # The file storing the process ID of the main process
   pid /var/run/nginx/nginx.pid;
   include custom.d/*.conf;

   http {

     # Hide Nginx version information.
     include h5bp/security/server_software_information.conf;

     # Specify media (MIME) types for files.
     include h5bp/media_types/media_types.conf;

     # Set character encodings.
     include h5bp/media_types/character_encodings.conf;

     # Include $http_x_forwarded_for within default format used in log files
     # https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#log_format
     log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                       '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                       '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
     access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;

     keepalive_timeout 20s;
     sendfile on;
     tcp_nopush on;

     # Specify file cache expiration.
     include h5bp/web_performance/cache_expiration.conf;

     # Add X-Frame-Options for HTML documents.
     # h5bp/security/x-frame-options.conf
     map $sent_http_content_type $x_frame_options {
       ~*text/html DENY;
     }

     # Add Content-Security-Policy for HTML documents.
     # h5bp/security/content-security-policy.conf
     map $sent_http_content_type $content_security_policy {
       ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests";
     }

     # Add Permissions-Policy for HTML documents.
     # h5bp/security/permissions-policy.conf
     map $sent_http_content_type $permissions_policy {
       ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),display-capture=(),document-domain=(),encrypted-media=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),midi=(),payment=(),picture-in-picture=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),sync-xhr=(self),usb=(),web-share=(),xr-spatial-tracking=()";
     }

     # Add Referrer-Policy for HTML documents.
     # h5bp/security/referrer-policy.conf
     map $sent_http_content_type $referrer_policy {
       ~*text/(css|html|javascript)|application\/pdf|xml "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
     }

     # Add Cross-Origin-Policies for HTML documents.
     # h5bp/security/cross-origin-policy.conf
     # Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
     map $sent_http_content_type $coep_policy {
       ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "require-corp";
     }
     # Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy
     map $sent_http_content_type $coop_policy {
       ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
     }
     # Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy
     map $sent_http_content_type $corp_policy {
       ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
     }

     # Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
     map $sent_http_content_type $cors {
       # Images
       ~*image/ "*";

       # Web fonts
       ~*font/                         "*";
       ~*application/vnd.ms-fontobject "*";
       ~*application/x-font-ttf        "*";
       ~*application/font-woff         "*";
       ~*application/x-font-woff       "*";
       ~*application/font-woff2        "*";
     }

     include conf.d/*.conf;

   }

   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Server software information                                        |
   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   server_tokens off;

   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Media types                                                        |
   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   include mime.types;

   default_type application/octet-stream;

   # configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:
   types {

     # Data interchange
       application/atom+xml                  atom;
       application/json                      json map topojson;
       application/ld+json                   jsonld;
       application/rss+xml                   rss;
       application/geo+json                  geojson;
       application/xml                       xml;
       application/rdf+xml                   rdf;

     # JavaScript
       # Servers should use text/javascript for JavaScript resources.
       text/javascript                       js mjs;
       application/wasm                      wasm;

     # Manifest files
       application/manifest+json             webmanifest;
       application/x-web-app-manifest+json   webapp;
       text/cache-manifest                   appcache;

     # Media files
       audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
       audio/mp4                             aac f4a f4b m4a;
       audio/mpeg                            mp3;
       audio/ogg                             oga ogg opus;
       audio/x-realaudio                     ra;
       audio/x-wav                           wav;
       image/apng                            apng;
       image/avif                            avif avifs;
       image/bmp                             bmp;
       image/gif                             gif;
       image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
       image/jxl                             jxl;
       image/jxr                             jxr hdp wdp;
       image/png                             png;
       image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
       image/tiff                            tif tiff;
       image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
       image/webp                            webp;
       image/x-jng                           jng;
       video/3gpp                            3gp 3gpp;
       video/mp4                             f4p f4v m4v mp4;
       video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
       video/ogg                             ogv;
       video/quicktime                       mov;
       video/webm                            webm;
       video/x-flv                           flv;
       video/x-mng                           mng;
       video/x-ms-asf                        asf asx;
       video/x-msvideo                       avi;
       image/x-icon                          cur ico;


     # Microsoft Office
       application/msword                                                         doc;
       application/vnd.ms-excel                                                   xls;
       application/vnd.ms-powerpoint                                              ppt;
       application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
       application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
       application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;


     # Web fonts
       font/woff                             woff;
       font/woff2                            woff2;
       application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
       font/ttf                              ttf;
       font/collection                       ttc;
       font/otf                              otf;

     # Other
       application/java-archive              ear jar war;
       application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
       application/octet-stream              bin deb dll dmg exe img iso msi msm msp safariextz;
       application/pdf                       pdf;
       application/postscript                ai eps ps;
       application/rtf                       rtf;
       application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
       application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
       application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
       application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
       application/x-bb-appworld             bbaw;
       application/x-bittorrent              torrent;
       application/x-chrome-extension        crx;
       application/x-cocoa                   cco;
       application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
       application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
       application/x-makeself                run;
       application/x-opera-extension         oex;
       application/x-perl                    pl pm;
       application/x-pilot                   pdb prc;
       application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
       application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
       application/x-sea                     sea;
       application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
       application/x-stuffit                 sit;
       application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
       application/x-x509-ca-cert            crt der pem;
       application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
       application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
       application/xslt+xml                  xsl;
       application/zip                       zip;
       text/calendar                         ics;
       text/css                              css;
       text/csv                              csv;
       text/html                             htm html shtml;
       text/markdown                         md markdown;
       text/mathml                           mml;
       text/plain                            txt;
       text/vcard                            vcard vcf;
       text/vnd.rim.location.xloc            xloc;
       text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
       text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
       text/vtt                              vtt;
       text/x-component                      htc;

   }

   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
   # | Character encodings                                                |
   # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

   charset utf-8;
   charset_types
       text/css
       text/plain
       text/vnd.wap.wml
       text/javascript
       text/markdown
       text/calendar
       text/x-component
       text/vcard
       text/cache-manifest
       text/vtt
       application/json
       application/manifest+json;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Config file for mydomain.com host                                   |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

     server {
       listen 80;
       listen [::]:80;

       server_name www.mydomain.com mydomain.com;

       return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
     }

     server {
       listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
       listen 443 ssl http2;

       server_name mydomain.com;

       include h5bp/tls/ssl_engine.conf;
       include h5bp/tls/certificate_files.conf;
       include h5bp/tls/policy_balanced.conf;

       return 301 $scheme://www.mydomain.com$request_uri;
     }

     server {
       listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
       listen 443 ssl http2;

       # The host name to respond to
       server_name www.mydomain.com;

       include h5bp/tls/ssl_engine.conf;
       include h5bp/tls/certificate_files.conf;
       include h5bp/tls/policy_balanced.conf;

       # Path for static files
       root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;
       location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
         }

       include h5bp/errors/custom_errors.conf;
       include h5bp/basic.conf;

       # php-fpm
       index index.php index.html;
       location ~* \.php$ {
         fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php8.1-fpm.sock;
         fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
         fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
         fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
         fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
         fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
         fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
         fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
         fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
         fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
         fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
         fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
         fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
         fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
         fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
         fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
         fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
         fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

         # PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
         fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
         fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
      }
     }

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | SSL engine                                                         |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     ssl_session_timeout 24h;
     ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
     keepalive_timeout 300s;
     ssl_session_tickets off;
     ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Certificate files                                                  |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
     ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
     ssl_dhparam             /etc/letsencrypt/dhparam.pem;

     ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/chain.pem;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | SSL policy - Balanced                                              |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
     ssl_ciphers "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHAZO-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384";

     ssl_ecdh_curve secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Custom error messages/pages                                        |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     error_page 404 /404.html;

     # configuration file /etc/nginx/h5bp/basic.conf:
     include h5bp/security/referrer-policy.conf;
     include h5bp/security/x-content-type-options.conf;
     include h5bp/security/x-frame-options.conf;
     include h5bp/location/security_file_access.conf;
     include h5bp/cross-origin/requests.conf;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Referrer Policy                                                    |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

     # Set a strict Referrer Policy to mitigate information leakage.

     add_header Referrer-Policy $referrer_policy always;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Content Type Options                                               |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

     add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;

     # configuration file /etc/nginx/h5bp/security/x-frame-options.conf:
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Frame Options                                                      |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     add_header X-Frame-Options $x_frame_options always;

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | File access                                                        |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------

     location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
       deny all;
     }

     location ~* (?:#.*#|\.(?:bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|orig|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
       deny all;
     }

     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     # | Cross-origin requests                                              |
     # ----------------------------------------------------------------------
     add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors;
   ```
6. My php-fpm configuration looks like this
   /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf: >>

   ```
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; FPM Configuration ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Global Options ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

   [global]
   pid = /var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.pid

   ; Error log file
   error_log = /var/log/php8.1-fpm.log

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Pool Definitions ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   include=/etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/*.conf
   ```

   /etc/php/8.1/fpm/php.ini >>

   ```
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Language Options ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   engine = On
   short_open_tag = Off
   precision = 14
   output_buffering = 4096
   zlib.output_compression = Off
   implicit_flush = Off
   unserialize_callback_func =
   serialize_precision = -1
   disable_functions =
   disable_classes =
   zend.enable_gc = On
   zend.exception_ignore_args = On
   zend.exception_string_param_max_len = 0

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Miscellaneous ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   expose_php = Off

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Resource Limits ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   max_execution_time = 30
   max_input_time = 60
   memory_limit = 128M

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Error handling and logging ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
   display_errors = Off
   display_startup_errors = Off
   log_errors = On
   ignore_repeated_errors = Off
   ignore_repeated_source = Off
   report_memleaks = On

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Data Handling ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   variables_order = "GPCS"
   request_order = "GP"
   register_argc_argv = Off
   auto_globals_jit = On
   post_max_size = 8M
   auto_prepend_file =
   auto_append_file =
   default_mimetype = "text/html"
   default_charset = "UTF-8"

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Paths and Directories ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   doc_root =
   user_dir =
   enable_dl = Off
   cgi.force_redirect = 1
   fastcgi.logging = 1

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; File Uploads ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   file_uploads = Off
   upload_max_filesize = 2M
   max_file_uploads = 20

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Fopen wrappers ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   allow_url_fopen = On
   allow_url_include = Off

   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   ; Module Settings ;
   ;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
   cli_server.color = On

   pdo_mysql.default_socket=

   SMTP = localhost
   smtp_port = 25

   odbc.allow_persistent = On
   odbc.check_persistent = On
   odbc.max_persistent = -1
   odbc.max_links = -1
   odbc.defaultlrl = 4096
   odbc.defaultbinmode = 1

   mysqli.max_persistent = -1
   mysqli.allow_persistent = On
   mysqli.max_links = -1
   mysqli.default_port = 3306
   mysqli.default_socket =
   mysqli.default_host =
   mysqli.default_user =
   mysqli.default_pw =
   mysqli.reconnect = Off
   mysqlnd.collect_statistics = On
   mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics = Off

   pgsql.allow_persistent = On
   pgsql.auto_reset_persistent = Off
   pgsql.max_persistent = -1
   pgsql.max_links = -1
   pgsql.ignore_notice = 0
   pgsql.log_notice = 0
   bcmath.scale = 0

   session.save_handler = files
   session.use_strict_mode = 0
   session.use_cookies = 1
   session.use_only_cookies = 1
   session.name = PHPSESSID
   session.auto_start = 0
   session.cookie_lifetime = 0
   session.cookie_path = /
   session.cookie_domain =
   session.cookie_httponly =
   session.cookie_samesite =
   session.serialize_handler = php
   session.gc_probability = 0
   session.gc_divisor = 1000
   session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
   session.referer_check =
   session.cache_limiter = nocache
   session.cache_expire = 180
   session.use_trans_sid = 0
   session.sid_length = 26
   session.trans_sid_tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form="
   session.sid_bits_per_character = 5

   [Assertion]
   zend.assertions = -1

   [Tidy]
   tidy.clean_output = Off

   [soap]
   ; Enables or disables WSDL caching feature.
   soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
   soap.wsdl_cache_dir="/tmp"
   soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
   soap.wsdl_cache_limit = 5

   [ldap]
   ldap.max_links = -1
   ```

   /etc/php/8.1/fpm/pool.d/www.conf >>

   ```
    ; Start a new pool named 'www'.
    [www]

    ; Unix user/group of processes
    user = www-data
    group = www-data

    ; The address on which to accept FastCGI requests.
    listen = /var/run/php8.1-fpm.sock

    ; Set permissions for unix socket, if one is used. In Linux, read/write
    ; permissions must be set in order to allow connections from a web server. Many
    ; BSD-derived systems allow connections regardless of permissions. The owner
    ; and group can be specified either by name or by their numeric IDs.
    listen.owner = www-data
    listen.group = www-data
    listen.mode = 0660

    ; Choose how the process manager will control the number of child processes.
    pm = dynamic

    ; The number of child processes to be created when pm is set to 'static' and the
    ; maximum number of child processes when pm is set to 'dynamic' or 'ondemand'.
    pm.max_children = 5

    ; The number of child processes created on startup.
    pm.start_servers = 2

    ; The desired minimum number of idle server processes.
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1

    ; The desired maximum number of idle server processes.
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3

    ; Chroot to this directory at the start. This value must be defined as an
    chroot = /var/www/the-ts.com

    ; Chdir to this directory at the start.
    chdir = /
   ```

There are no noteworthy errors in /var/log/nginx/access.log or /var/log/nginx/error.log  nor in /var/log/php-fpm.log

All systemctl status querries for nginx and php-fpm look good.

ufw has been enabled and the ports for 'OpenSSH' and 'Nginx Full' have been allowed.

Comment: Do you use Cloudflare? Have you tried without proxy on?

Comment: Yes, I use cloudflare. And indeed I tried it without proxy. Unfortunately, that didn't make the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot say for sure what's the problem with my configuration above. Instead I'll share my working configuration for others with the same problem.

```
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user                                          www-data;
pid                                           /run/nginx.pid;
worker_processes                              auto;
worker_rlimit_nofile                          65535;

# Load modules
include                                       /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    multi_accept                              on;
    worker_connections                        65535;
}

http {
    sendfile                                  on;
    tcp_nopush                                on;
    tcp_nodelay                               on;
    server_tokens                             off;
    log_not_found                             off;
    client_max_body_size                      16M;

    # MIME
    include                                   mime.types;
    default_type                              application/octet-stream;

   # Set character encodings.
    charset utf-8;
    charset_types
      text/css
      text/plain
      text/vnd.wap.wml
      text/javascript
      text/markdown
      text/calendar
      text/x-component
      text/vcard
      text/cache-manifest
      text/vtt
      application/json
      application/manifest+json;

    # Log Format
    log_format                                cloudflare '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" $status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" $http_cf_ray $http_cf_connecting_ip $http_x_forwarded_for $http_x_forwarded_proto $http_true_client_ip $http_cf_ipcountry $http_cf_visitor';

    # Logging
    #access_log                                /var/log/nginx/access.log cloudflare;
    #error_log                                 /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;

    # Cacheing
    open_file_cache                           max=1000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid                     30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses                  2;
    open_file_cache_errors                    on;

    # Specify file cache expiration.
    map $sent_http_content_type $expires {
      default                                 1y;

      # No content
      ""                                      off;

      # CSS
      ~*text/css                              1y;

      # Data interchange
      ~*application/atom\+xml                 1h;
      ~*application/rdf\+xml                  1h;
      ~*application/rss\+xml                  1h;

      ~*application/json                      0;
      ~*application/ld\+json                  0;
      ~*application/schema\+json              0;
      ~*application/geo\+json                 0;
      ~*application/xml                       0;
      ~*text/calendar                         0;
      ~*text/xml                              0;

      # Favicon (cannot be renamed!) and cursor images
      ~*image/vnd.microsoft.icon              1w;
      ~*image/x-icon                          1w;

      # HTML
      ~*text/html                             0;

      # JavaScript
      ~*application/javascript                1y;
      ~*application/x-javascript              1y;
      ~*text/javascript                       1y;

      # Manifest files
      ~*application/manifest\+json            1w;
      ~*application/x-web-app-manifest\+json  0;
      ~*text/cache-manifest                   0;

      # Markdown
      ~*text/markdown                         0;

      # Media files
      ~*audio/                                1y;
      ~*image/                                1y;
      ~*video/                                1y;

      # WebAssembly
      ~*application/wasm                      1y;

      # Web fonts
      ~*font/                                 1y;
      ~*application/vnd.ms-fontobject         1y;
      ~*application/x-font-ttf                1y;
      ~*application/x-font-woff               1y;
      ~*application/font-woff                 1y;
      ~*application/font-woff2                1y;

      # Other
      ~*text/x-cross-domain-policy            1w;
    }
    expires $expires;


    # Add X-Frame-Options for HTML documents.
    map $sent_http_content_type $x_frame_options {
        ~*text/html DENY;
    }

    # Add Content-Security-Policy for HTML documents.
    map $sent_http_content_type $content_security_policy {
        ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "default-src 'self'; base-uri 'none'; form-action 'self'; frame-ancestors 'none'; object-src 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests";
    }

    # Add Permissions-Policy for HTML documents.
    map $sent_http_content_type $permissions_policy {
        ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "accelerometer=(),autoplay=(),camera=(),display-capture=(),document-domain=(),encrypted-media=(),fullscreen=(),geolocation=(),gyroscope=(),magnetometer=(),microphone=(),midi=(),payment=(),picture-in-picture=(),publickey-credentials-get=(),screen-wake-lock=(),sync-xhr=(self),usb=(),web-share=(),xr-spatial-tracking=()";
    }

    # Add Referrer-Policy for HTML documents.
    map $sent_http_content_type $referrer_policy {
        ~*text/(css|html|javascript)|application\/pdf|xml "strict-origin-when-cross-origin";
    }

    # Add Cross-Origin-Policies for HTML documents.
    # Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy
    map $sent_http_content_type $coep_policy {
        ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "require-corp";
    }

    # Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy
    map $sent_http_content_type $coop_policy {
        ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
    }

    # Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy
    map $sent_http_content_type $corp_policy {
        ~*text/(html|javascript)|application/pdf|xml "same-origin";
    }

    # Add Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
    map $sent_http_content_type $cors {
        # Images
        ~*image/ "*";

        # Web fonts
        ~*font/                         "*";
        ~*application/vnd.ms-fontobject "*";
        ~*application/x-font-ttf        "*";
        ~*application/font-woff         "*";
        ~*application/x-font-woff       "*";
        ~*application/font-woff2        "*";
    }


    # Load configs
    include                                  /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    # MyDoMain.de
    server {
        listen                               MyIP:443 ssl http2;
        listen                               [MyIPv6]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name                          www.MyDoMain.de;

        set                                  $base /var/www/MyDoMain.de;
        root                                 $base/public;

        # SSL
        include                              ssl.conf;

        # restrict methods
        if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|POST|HEAD)$) {
            return '405';
        }

        # logging
        access_log /var/www/log/nginx.access.log cloudflare;
        error_log  /var/www/log/nginx.error.log warn;

        # index.php
        index      index.php;

        # index.html fallback
        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
            if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
                # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
                # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
                add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
                add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
                add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
                return 204;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'POST') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
            if ($request_method = 'GET') {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range' always;
                add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range' always;
            }
        }

        # index.php fallback
        location ~ ^/var/www/MyDoMain.de/ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # favicon.ico
        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log    off;
        }

        # robots.txt
        location = /robots.txt {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log    off;
        }

        # assets, media
        location ~* \.(?:css(\.map)?|js(\.map)?|jpe?g|png|gif|ico|cur|heic|webp|tiff?|mp3|m4a|aac|ogg|midi?|wav|mp4|mov|webm|mpe?g|avi|ogv|flv|wmv)$ {
            expires    7d;
            access_log off;
        }

        # svg, fonts
        location ~* \.(?:svgz?|ttf|ttc|otf|eot|woff2?)$ {
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
            expires    7d;
            access_log off;
        }

        # handle .php
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass                    unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm.sock;

            # 404
            try_files                       $fastcgi_script_name =404;

            # default fastcgi_params
            include                         fastcgi.conf;

            # fastcgi settings
            fastcgi_index                   index.php;
            fastcgi_buffers                 8 16k;
            fastcgi_buffer_size             32k;
        }

        # Referrer Policy
        add_header Referrer-Policy $referrer_policy always;

        # X-Content-Type-Options
        add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff always;

        # X-Frame-Options
        add_header X-Frame-Options $x_frame_options always;

        # Security-File-Access
        location ~* /\.(?!well-known\/) {
          deny all;
        }

        location ~* (?:#.*#|\.(?:bak|conf|dist|fla|in[ci]|log|orig|psd|sh|sql|sw[op])|~)$ {
          deny all;
        }

        # Cross-Origin-Requests
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin $cors;

    }

    # non-www, subdomains redirect, ssl
    server {
        listen                              MyIP:443 ssl http2;
        listen                              [MyIPv6]:443 ssl http2;

        server_name                         .MyDoMain.de;

        # SSL
        include                             ssl.conf;

        # redirect
        return                              301 https://www.MyDoMain.de$request_uri;
    }

    # HTTP redirect
    server {
        listen                              MyIP:80;
        listen                              [MyIPv6]:80;

        server_name                         www.MyDoMain.de MyDoMain.de;

        # redirect
        location / {
            return 301                      https://www.MyDoMain.de$request_uri;
        }
    }
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-auth-pam.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_auth_pam_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-cache-purge.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_cache_purge_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-dav-ext.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_dav_ext_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-echo.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_echo_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-fancyindex.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_fancyindex_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-headers-more-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_headers_more_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-perl.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_perl_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-subs-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_subs_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-uploadprogress.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_uploadprogress_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-upstream-fair.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_upstream_fair_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-nchan.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_nchan_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/70-mod-stream-geoip2.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_geoip2_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/ssl.conf:
# SSL
ssl_session_timeout             1d;
ssl_session_cache               shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_tickets             off;

ssl_protocols                   TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
ssl_ciphers                     "ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHAZO-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384";
ssl_ecdh_curve                  secp521r1:secp384r1:prime256v1;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers       on;

# Create session ticket key:    openssl rand -out /etc/nginx/ssl/session_ticket_key 48
ssl_session_ticket_key          /etc/nginx/ssl/session_ticket_key;

# Create dhparam4096.pem:       openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam4096.pem 4096
ssl_dhparam                     /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

# OCSP Stapling
ssl_stapling                    on;
ssl_stapling_verify             on;
resolver                        1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1 [2606:4700:4700::1111] [2606:4700:4700::1001] 208.67.222.222 208.67.220.220 [2620:119:35::35] [2620:119:53::53] valid=60s;
resolver_timeout                2s;

# set certificate files
ssl_certificate                 /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDoMain.de/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key             /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDoMain.de/privkey.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/MyDoMain.de/chain.pem;

add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf:

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_USER        $remote_user;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

- a VPS server with it's own IP
- a CloudFlare account with YourDomain.com pointing to a Cloudflare IP.

Once you've  started the VPS, you put it's IP into cloudflare as the *backend* for that domain.

When I lookup YourDomain.com I'll get the cloudflare IP, and when I point a web browser at YourDomain.com, It'll connect to cloudflare which will forward that request to your VPS.

Just running nginx on it should be enough to see the basic 'YourDomain.com/index.html'.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand you correct. I have a VPS thats true and I am using CF in order to manage DNS and as registrar. However, my CF DNS A/AAAA entries are pointing to the VPS's IP as it should be. In the meanwhile I found out that changing the server directive in /etc/nginx/conf.d/mydomain.com.conf to `server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.mydomain.com;

    location / {
        root /var/www/mydomain.com/public;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}` lets me connect. The problem seems to be with wron redirects...

Comment: Maybe check that both "www.mydomain.com" and "mydomain.com" point to your VPS's IP. Use a CNAME in the DNS setup for this. Be aware that DNS server entries have timeouts (TTL = time-to-live), so can take a while for the change to show up. I would use "Listen *:80" or "Listen (your actual VPS IP):80". HTTPS will require "Listen *:443" likewise.